# Formal names of nested functions

Tags: terminology, reference-request, programming-languages

I have a nested function as follow:

```
def make_adder(n):
    def add(x):
        return x + n
    return add
>>> plus_3 = make_adder(3)
>>> plus_5 = make_adder(5)
>>> plus_3(4) 7
>>> plus_5(4) 9
```

What's the formal names of `make_adder` and `add`?
Can I call them 'outer function' and 'inner function'?

Comment: I can't think of a completely standard term, but I believe your terms (outer/inner) are sometimes used. I think I also heard top-level/nested function, and global/local function. None of these term properly "scale" to multiple nestings, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that either takes a function as argument or returns a function as result is called a [High Order Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) in functional programming. Your function `make_adder` is doing the latter.

Answer (score 0):

One specific name for that kind of construct is "[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))". That term specifically refers to a situation where the inner function uses variables from the outer function's "enclosing" namespace.

Comment: That term is uses for so many different things, it hardly qualifies as "formal".